# Why is not looping?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning python and I'm not sure why the output of the below code is only "False"  and not many "false" if I created a loop and the list of dict have 5 elements.
I was expect an ouput like 
"False" 
"False"
"False"
"False"

```
"False"

movies = [{
      "name": "Usual Suspects"
    }, {
        "name": "Hitman",

    }, {
        "name": "Dark Knight",

    },{
        "name": "The Choice",

    }, {
        "name": "Colonia",}
  ]


def peliMayor(p):
    index= -1
    for n in movies:
        index= index + 1
        if (movies[index]['name'] == p):
            return print("True")
        else:
            return print("False")


peli = "Thriller"
peliMayor(peli)
```

Comment: because you are returning up front, replace return with print and you will see the desired result

Comment: Is is stopping because you have a `return`, which ends the loop.

Comment: remove the `return`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `return` from your for-loop as it breaks your loop.
Also, the `if-else` statement is not required. You can print the boolean value directly from the comparison  `movies[index]['name'] == p`

```
def peliMayor(p):
    index= -1
    for n in movies:
        index= index + 1
        print(movies[index]['name'] == p)

movies = [{'name': 'Usual Suspects'}, {'name': 'Hitman'},
          {'name': 'Dark Knight'}, {'name': 'The Choice'},
          {'name': 'Colonia'}]

peli = 'Thriller'
peliMayor(peli)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove return from loop. The following code will help you. Thanks.

```
movies = [{'name': 'Usual Suspects'}, {'name': 'Hitman'},
          {'name': 'Dark Knight'}, {'name': 'The Choice'},
          {'name': 'Colonia'}]


def peliMayor(p):
    index = -1
    for n in movies:
        index = index + 1
        if movies[index]['name'] == p:
            print 'True'
        else:
            print 'False'


peli = 'Thriller'
peliMayor(peli)
```